# Postgres is not loading the Patroni YAML configuration

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I have created the three-node Patroni cluster. The Patroni configuration are showing as we provided in the Patroni YAML file:

```yaml
postgres@postgresql0:~$ patronictl -c /etc/patroni.yaml show-config

loop_wait: 10
maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
postgresql:
  parameters:
    autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay: 1ms
    autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: 5000
    lock_timeout: 25000ms
    log_autovacuum_min_duration: 60s
    log_destination: csvlog
    log_directory: pg_log
    log_line_prefix: 'time=%t, pid=%p %q db=%d, usr=%u, client=%h , app=%a, line=%l '
    log_lock_waits: true
    log_min_duration_statement: 5s
    log_min_messages: info
    log_statement: none
    logging_collector: true
    maintenance_work_mem: 2GB
    max_connections: 10000
    max_replication_slots: 10
    max_wal_size: 500GB
    min_wal_size: 500GB
    random_page_cost: 1.0
    wal_buffers: -1
    wal_keep_segments: 320
    wal_level: logical
    wal_sender_timeout: 0
  use_pg_rewind: true
  use_slots: true
retry_timeout: 10
ttl: 30
```

But when we are checking in the `psql` console , it is giving the default configuration of Postgres.

```
postgres@postgresql0:~$ psql

postgres=# show autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay;

 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay 
------------------------------
 2ms
(1 row)

postgres=# show max_connections;

 max_connections 
-----------------
 100
(1 row)*
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and correct it?

PostgreSQL should load the parameters that are provided in the Patroni YAML.

Comment: I cannot explain the `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` effect, but you need to restart PostgreSQL to change `max_connections`.